# Access to array offset on value of type int - drupal

Tags: php, drupal, render

I'm doing a personnal project using Drupal. In localhost everything is working fine but when I put it on my raspberry server i have this error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 81 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

I have far more error but its all like this one. I looked on the internet and there is a lot of information saying that it comes from php. I'm using PHP 7.2.4 and the server is using php 7.4.6.

Information about my server:

> Raspberry pi 3 model b, os raspbian

If you need more information, I can provide it to you.

Cordially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the version difference of **PHP 7.2.4** and **PHP 7.4.6** can explain the different behavior.

1. Why not installing 7.4.6 on your local machine and test the code with exact same PHP as your final target (raspberry pi)?
2. or downgrade the PHP on your raspberry pi to 7.2.4?

you could give it a try to **downgrade raspberry pi to PHP7.2**:

1. create a backup of your SD card
2. install PHP7.2 `sudo apt install -y php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common`
3. make PHP7.2 the default `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2`
4. double check `php -v` should tell PHP7.2
5. done

Comment: I can't, its too difficult to change without having a ton of error...

Comment: Do you need support for (1) or (2) ?

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Well, I bought an OVH server, I did put the project into my www/ folder but still has an error `The provided host name is not valid for this server.`

Comment: I just checked, there are multiple issues with drupal and PHP7.4 as of now. So I suggest to downgrade and go with PHP7.2.4.

Comment: I just added some short notes on downgrade your raspberry pi to PHP7.2